# How do i get the access token in validate method before passport callback decodes?

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js

```js
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    
    constructor(private readonly accountService: AccountService,
        @InjectRepository(BlacklistRepository) private blacklistRepository: BlacklistRepository,
        private readonly customerService: CustomerService,
    ) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            // ignoreExpiration: true,
            secretOrKey: config['jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.base64-secret'],
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: Payload, done: VerifiedCallback): Promise<any> {
        
        console.log(accessToken) // i need it here as 'Bearer e*****.....'
     
        if (!user) {
            return done(new UnauthorizedException({ message: 'user does not exist' }), false);
        }
        return done(null, user);
    }
}
```

I need to get the access token in validate method to check for revoked token in database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to get to `validate` without passport first decoding the token and validating it. **However** you can add `passReqToCallback: true` to the `super` options in the `constructor` and then `req` will be the **first** parameter of the `validate` method and you can do `const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']` to get the raw bearer token

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {

  constructor(private readonly accountService: AccountService,
    @InjectRepository(BlacklistRepository) private blacklistRepository: BlacklistRepository,
    private readonly customerService: CustomerService,
) {
    super({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        // ignoreExpiration: true,
        secretOrKey: config['jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.base64-secret'],
        passReqToCallback: true
    });
  }

  async validate(req: express.Request, payload: Payload, done: VerifiedCallback): Promise<any> {
    const accessToken = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(accessToken) // i need it here as 'Bearer e*****.....'
 
    if (!user) {
        return done(new UnauthorizedException({ message: 'user does not exist' }), false);
    }
    return done(null, user);
  }

}
```

Comment: so how to decrypt the token first (if it was encrypted), before Passport start to verify jwt token format from  `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()` (or cookie extract)?

Comment: @alucard I'm not sure I understand what the question is here

Comment: I mean in the context if the token (which is already signed) and you encrypt again because you want to hide the payload data. So you have to decrypt first before Passport validate it, maybe decrypt it first in canActivate (since you can access request?) after decrypt then put back into bearer request?

Comment: Passport should be aware of the encryption method you use and the secret/signature you used to sign the key. It'll handle decrypting it and verifying the JWT before you get to the `validate` method for any custom validation logic you want to handle